# KML IconStyle color entered as blue but displays red in Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz

I'm using hexadecimal colors to label icons.  For blue I'm using `0000ff`. In the KML file it is as `<color>ff0000ff</color>`.  However, when the KML is opened in Google Earth the icon placemark is red.

Looking at https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference my take is color should be coded as `ff` + `hexadecimal number`, therefore black is represented as `ff000000`, which works, but `ff0000ff` for blue does not.

I've tried various style and icon options without success.  I've read and seen how there is a layering effect that will merge the icon and color.  It seems using a wht-blank.png would be a neutral canvas to apply a color, but I suspect it could be interfering.

Below is my test kml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>kml_test</name>
        <Placemark>
            <name>uniq_name</name>
            <Style>
                <IconStyle>
                    <scale>1</scale>
                    <color>ff0000ff</color>
                    <Icon>
                        <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-blank.png</href>
                    </Icon>
                </IconStyle>
            </Style>
            <LabelStyle>
                <color>ffffffff</color>
                <scale>0.6</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>-118.000000</longitude>
                <latitude>34.000000</latitude>
                <range>1000</range>
            </LookAt>
            <Point>
                <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                <extrude>0</extrude>
                <coordinates>-118.000000,34.000000,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

I expect `<color>ff0000ff</color>` to show a blue icon when kml is opened in Google Earth, not red.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

KML does not use normal color order, instead it is in reversed order of Blue, Green, Red, or: AABBGGRR, where AA is the alpha or transparency, BB is blue, GG is Green and RR is Red.

For more info see the documentation for the `<color>` tag, here:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#elements-specific-to-colorstyle

specifically this line:

```
The order of expression is aabbggrr
```

For a blue icon you'll want to use: `<color>ffff0000</color>`

Comment: The documentation wasn't making sense but your answer clarifies.  Hexadecimal is R-G-B, and the KML pattern needs to be flipped to B-G-R.  Perfect!

Comment: what is ABGR format called?